# My user is gone when i refresh page ReactJS NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

I am a beginner at React and started making a Full Stack app (a small Blog app with authentication).
I use the JWT token that I put in the Cookie when the User Login. I print the name of the logged in user in the header. It does it all perfectly until the page refreshes. When I refresh the page I can still access protected routes because I have a JWT cookie in Storage, but I lose the entire user object, when the user login the object is full of user information and when I refresh the page the object is empty.

This is my React Reducer:

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = { user: {} }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true, isAuthenticated: false };
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        isAuthenticated: true,
        user: action.payload,
      };
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, error: action.payload };
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return { loading: false, isAuthenticated: false, user: null };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my React Action:

```
const { data } = await API.post(
  '/api/v1/users/login',
  { email, password },
  config
);
 dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });
} catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    });
  }
};
```

API is config for Axios:

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8000',
  withCredentials: true,
  credentials: 'include',
});
```

And this is my Login Screen:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const redirect = location.search ? location.search.split('=')[1] : '/';

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userLogin = useSelector(state => state.userLogin);
  const { loading, error, isAuthenticated } = userLogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `user: action.payload` the user object?

These data aren't being stored in the cookie so they will not persist after page refresh. You'll want to re-fetch on refresh or store them in a persistent storage such as localStorage and check it before you fetch.

**Update:**

> Yes, user: action.payload is user object, and after refresh its empty. Can you give me some advice how to re fetch again user?

A temporary fix would be to make fetch request by calling the action that you've created for the reducer:

- USER_LOGIN_REQUEST
- USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS

Trigger the login request by providing the JWT token to your backend service to authenticate. Return the authenticated response. You can use one of the React lifecycle hook in the component to do this (ex. componentDidMount). I don't think this is a good long term solution though. You may want to look up React authentication examples and make that fetch request before the component even gets mounted since this seems like a app-wide requirement.

You've mentioned using JWT and cookie together and that may mean reading from the cookie or using the cookie and JWT alone as security. This may not be sufficient to protect your users. [OWASP](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/JSON_Web_Token_for_Java_Cheat_Sheet.html) has some recommendations that you can review separately for JWT security.

Comment: Yes, user: action.payload is user object, and after refresh its empty. Can you give me some advice how to re fetch again user?

Comment: @valkkorn I've updaetd my answer. Hopefully it'll help point you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After you dispatch USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS in your Thunk, you can add the user information to local storage:

```
const { data } = await API.post(
  '/api/v1/users/login',
  { email, password },
  config
);
  dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    });

  // Setting user to local storage
  localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data));

} catch (error) {...}};
```

Then in your store.js file (or whatever file you configure your store in), you can get the user object from local storage and add it to the initial state, like so:

```
const user = localStorage.getItem('user')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
  : { user: null };

const initialState = {
  // Add the user object from local storage to whatever slice of state is appropriate
  auth: { user, loading: false },
  ...
  };
```

---

**Fetch on page refresh**

To fetch the user upon refreshing the page I would add a useEffect hook to my app.js file:

```
// /app.js
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(login())
}, [])
```

Comment: Yes it is good but is it secure enough so put user informations in local storage?

Comment: If you're worried about security you could run a hashing algorithm on the data before you save it to local storage.  bcrypt is a good library.  Store your secret key in your .env.

However, if it's just the user's name, last name, and email, I don't see a huge potentiality of security risk.

Comment: Is this application going to production or is it just an application for learning or your portfolio?  You said you were a beginner with React, and although it's good to ask questions and consider issues with security, I think it would be more beneficial to learn the patterns and fundamentals of React/Redux.

Comment: @valkkorn Keep in mind that JWT isn't secure. A user can read JWT content as well as JWT content inside unprotected cookies. See [OWASP - Storage APIs](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTML5_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html#storage-apis) for more in depth look at storage security.

Comment: @AK_ Yes, you are right. I am a beginner and I know that what I am doing is bad, but I just want to see how it is done in practice and to try to do something like that, not to start learning something in the wrong direction. Is it a good practice to create a route that will return the logged in user? I would call the function in App.js useEffect?